# Unexpected result of Not operator in assignment

Tags: verilog

I have two 8-bit inputs `A` and `B`,

```
input [7:0] A,B;
```

and a 9-bit output `F`,

```
output reg [8:0] F;
```

`A` and `B` are combined and assigned to `F` like this:

```
F <= ~(A^B);
```

If `A` is equal to `8'hFF`, and `B` is equal to `8'hF0`, why does `F` become `9'h1F0` and not `9'h0F0`?

Answer (score 6):

> Why is the output 9'h1F0 and not 9'h0F0?

You defined F as 9 bits wide. Thus the compiler will expand the right-hand-side arguments to 9 bits **before** doing any operations.
As both A and B are unsigned they become resp
`A = 9'h0FF, B=9'h0F0.` EXOR gives 9'h00F. Ones complement then gives 9'h1F0.

Beware that the width expansion does not happen if you put the expression between {}:

```
F2 = {~(A^B)};
```

F2 will be 9'h0F0;

Answer (score 2):

Because sections *11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression* and *11.8.3 Steps for evaluating an assignment* of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM effectively say that the operands get extended first to match the size of the result before any operation is performed.